# Vue - Using plugin as prototype

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using [euvl/vue-notification](https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification) for notifications on my application. Every time I want to notify the user I need to write the following code:

If inside a Vue component:

```
this.$notify({
    group: 'panel',
    type: 'success',
    duration: 5000,
    text: 'message'
})
```

Or if inside a .js file:

```
Vue.notify({
    group: 'panel',
    type: 'success',
    duration: 5000,
    text: `message`
})
```

I want to create a support file, similar to [event bus](https://gist.github.com/caiokawasaki/e69deea43b4a326db138db24c36e3b37) and just call the following line to write a notification:

```
this.$notify('message')
```

This is what I tried until now but without success...

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import notifications from './support/notifications'

Vue.use(notifications)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`notifications.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'

Vue.use(Notifications)

export default function install(Vue) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$notify', {
        get(message) {
            return Vue.notify({
                group: 'panel',
                type: 'success',
                duration: 5000,
                text: message
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost achieved what do you want, except of using `Object.defineProperty`.
Try to return a `function` reference instead of `Vue.notify`'s return on `get` method.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'

Vue.use(Notifications)

export default function install(Vue) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue, 'notification', {
        get() {
            return notification;
        }
    })

    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$notification', {
        get() {
            return notification;
        }
    })
}

function notification(message) {
    Vue.notify({
        group: 'panel',
        type: 'success',
        duration: 5000,
        text: message
    })
}
```

Comment: E quem diria que uma simples função causaria esse problema hehe

Comment: Pois é. E quem diria que meu inglês esta tão ruim assim que os brasileiros já reconhecem,. huehueuhe

Comment: There is just one problem, inside .js files when I call: `Vue.notify('message', 'error')` nothing happens

Comment: I'm calling `Vue.$notify('message', 'error')` inside `store/modules/auth.js`, and I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.$notify is not a function`. May I need to import `notification`?

Comment: I think you may register the component in the same way it is done here: https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification/blob/4360cd79b1615b921f0d5c241d04ae6077f59551/src/index.js#L27.
I've adjusted my answer to clarify.

Comment: Also try to install the plugin in `index.js` file (root entrypoint).

Comment: Also, inside a component I'm calling `this.$notify()` inside an axios success promisse, and its always causing axios to call succes then the error

Comment: Probabily the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is caused by a circular call. I changed the custom plugin to '$notification' to avoid name conflicts. Could you test it?

Comment: Worked... One more thing for life, do not use the same names as the plugin uses...